# ERROR in : The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7.1 but unfortunately I am not able to make the translate pipe of ngx-translate to work…

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~2.1.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "~7.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~7.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// import ngx-translate and the http loader
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

export const APP_ID = 'test-app';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: APP_ID }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [ AppRoutingModule, TranslateModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    {{'demo.text' | translate}}
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.get('demo.text').subscribe((text: string) => { console.log('HERE: ', text); });
  }
}
```

I can see that the TranslateService works fine as it properly translate and output to the console successfully, however the pipe nor the [translate] works.

> ERROR in : The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("   [ERROR ->] 
>   {{'demo.text' | translate}}
>          ")

I see that this usually happens when the TranslateModule is not properly loaded in the imports, but it doesn't look to be the case since here it is properly loaded in app.module.ts and used in app.component.ts, which is bootstrapped by app.module.ts…

Any idea?

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce the issue

Comment: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule SharedModule is the part you should read

Comment: Stackblitz reproducing the problem: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhkb4e?embed=1)

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by importing and exporting the Translate module in my app's shared module. I don't think it should go in the routing module.

So my set up was as follows: 
app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'VetCafe'),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClient, AngularFireAuth],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { NgChatModule } from 'ng-chat';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgChatModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, TranslateModule,
    RouterModule, NgChatModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

A shared-ui.module for ui stuff:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule,
         MatCardModule, MatInputModule, MatDialogModule, MatTableModule,
         MatMenuModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule
       } from '@angular/material';

import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { SideNavigationComponent } from './side-navigation/side-navigation.component';

const matModules = [
  MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule,
  MatCardModule, MatInputModule, MatDialogModule, MatTableModule,
  MatMenuModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule
];

const moduleComponents = [
  NavigationComponent, FooterComponent, SideNavigationComponent
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    moduleComponents
  ],

  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    matModules
  ],

  exports: [
    FlexLayoutModule,
    matModules,
    moduleComponents
  ],
})
export class SharedUiModule { }
```

and finally my component template:

```
<nav class="app-navigation" [class.mat-elevation-z2]="!isActive" >
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxHide.gt-xs>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onToggleSidenav()"> 
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a routerLink="/">{{'HOME.Title' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="end" fxHide.xs>
        <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="15px" class="navigation-items">
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/forms/appointments']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >appointments</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/forms/clientreg']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >new client</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/forms/euthanasia']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >euthanasia</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/blog']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/services']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/legal/terms']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >terms</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/legal/privacy']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/account/signup']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >signup</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
              <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/account/login']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >login</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
              <a mat-button (click)="isLoggedIn = false">Log Out</a>
            </li>

            <li >
              <a mat-button (click)="changeLocale()">Language</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>

</nav>
```

Comment: This works for me. I have different modules too for my project structure.

Comment: thanks @alberto-l-bonfiglio your suggestion is helped me to understand the issue

Answer (score 10):

I faced these issue on angular `v12`

Error scenario:

1. On Visual Code.
2. Created new project.
3. Added @ngx-translate stuffs.
4. Completed all configuration related translations.
5. Used `{{ 'something' | translate}}` i.e. **Translate** pipe.

Error  shown as `The pipe 'translate' could not be found`.

I tried all solution and then I realized its issue of IDE because on terminal no error shown. All code is working smooth.

Simply I closed the Visual Code and Opened again.

Issue gone.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry guys. That was an easy one...
TranslateModule was well loaded in app.module, but not app-routing module which was an additional lazy router module to load app component.
Adding it there simply corrected the problem:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './welcome/welcome.module#WelcomeModule' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 4):

If using the translate directive in a template belonging to a feature module lazily loaded by the application routing module, then add the `TranslateModule` entry in the `export` array in the `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
    TranslateModule
  ]
```

There is no need to add a `TranslateModule` entry in the `import` array of the same file.

There is also no need to add a `TranslateModule` entry in the `export` array of the app module.

Also, the `TranslateModule` can be imported from within a custom core module instead of from within the app module. In a `core.module.ts` file have the following entry in the `import` array:

```
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [ HttpClient ]
      }
    })
  ]
```

There is no need to have any entry in the `export` array in this file.

In this same file, the `httpLoaderFactory` function is defined outside of the class:

```
export function httpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}
```

The translate service can then be used in the app component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService,
  ) {
    // The default language used as a fallback if a translation isn't found for the current language
    translateService.setDefaultLang(LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH);
    // The language to use
    translateService.use(LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello to all those who have the same issue. I have struggled with it trying many and many solutions with no success. In my case I had a *sharedmodule* that import *translatemodule* **forchild**, the *sharedmodule* was imported to all other modules of the app which uses lazyloading. Finally, I get why it was not working for me. **It was the position where I was importing the translatemodule/sharemodule**. It be should import just after *commonmodule* (second position of the @ngmodule imports array). In resume :

1. Make sure that you import the *translatemodule* just after the *commonmodule* or *browsermodule* (in appmodule)
2. If you use lazy loading make sure to import *translatemodule* **forchild** there
3. If you have a *sharedmodule* import *translatemodule* *forchild* (just after *commonmodule* as at 1) and **add Translatemodule in the export array**

In appmodule

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),...
```

In sharedmodule
in ngmodule
@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
TranslateModule.forChild(),..
and in export

```
 exports: [LoaderComponent, NavBarComponent, TranslateModule],
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, curiously, just changing the order of the imports on ngModule fixed the problem.

```
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     TranslateModule.forChild(),
```

It has to come right after CommonModule, not before.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Adding CommonModule to imports solved the issue for me. The error is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your `PLATFORM_PIPES` at your `bootstrap` like this:

```
{provide: PLATFORM_PIPES, useValue: TranslatePipe, multi: true}
```

This way you won't have to add it to the pipes property of your components.

Comment: Looks like deprecated after Angular 5.
Approach looks to either load TranslateModule in every module using it, or to have a SharedModule loaded.

Comment: @mr.Parth, can you explein me better plz ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a project with the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@angular/core": "~12.2.6",
  "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
  ...
}
```

And literally tried every single solution available on the internet including downgrading versions (for everything) with no luck.

Eventually ended up with something I don't yet understand, which is **adding the module that is using the `TranslateModule` to my `app.module.ts`**..

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TranslateModule.forChild** if the module is a lazy loading module.

```
imports: [
        TranslateModule.forChild({
          loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
              deps: [HttpClient]
          },
          isolate: true
      }),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my component wasn't declared in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that ***on a rare occasion*** getting this error may have nothing to do with your pipe implementation. In my case, a rogue mistyped parameter in some service method was the culprit. Rerunning the project gave me the right logs. So before you start desperately looking through all the local changes, give the ***restart*** a try.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because of missing dependency injection for ngx-translate service.

`import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";`

`private translate: TranslateService` add into your constructor() method on all the components where you are using translate pipe

It's working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to include imports for newly added components during a rebasing of my branch.  VSCode doesn't immediately tell me the module is missing these imports but instead proceeds to run the components which fail when trying to use pipes which are not being properly imported. Try checking your modules for any silent errors. [image]

Answer (score 0):

We can get this error in test, if we do not add **TranslateTestingModule**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations('en', {}),
      ],
      providers: [...]
    }).compileComponents();
```